# File DSN for iSeries AS400 ODBC connection

Tags: odbc, dsn

How can I create a file dsn for connecting to an AS400 system using the iSeries ODBC driver?

The iSeries ODBC driver allows many settings to be configured. Where can I find a list of all properties that can be set in the file DSN?

Answer (score 2):

*Driver={iSeries Access ODBC Driver};System=server;Uid=user;Pwd=password;*

Where server is the system to connect (either IP address or hostname), username and password.

You can have a .dsn file like this:

```
[ODBC]
DRIVER=iSeries Access ODBC Driver
System=server;
Uid=user;
Pwd=password;
Initial Catalog=library;
```

Comment: Where do I download iSeries Access ODBC Driver?

Comment: @endo64 if your societe work with AS400, they should have a software like iSeries Navigator, this software embed the ODBC driver

Answer (score 2):

There is a good internet resource regarding connectionstrings of all flavors:

[**http://www.connectionstrings.com/**](http://www.connectionstrings.com/)

Here is the page for the AS400 ODBC drivers: http://www.connectionstrings.com/as-400

---

### ODBC

**IBM Client Access ODBC driver**

```
Driver={Client Access ODBC Driver (32-bit)};System=my_system_name;
Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;
```

**IBM iSeries Access ODBC driver**

This driver is newer than the one above.

```
Driver={iSeries Access ODBC Driver};System=my_system_name;
Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;
```

### IBM .Net Data Provider

Using the IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries namespace

```
DataSource=myServerAddress;UserID=myUsername;
Password=myPassword; DataCompression=True;
```

### OLE DB, OleDbConnection

**IBM Client Access OLE DB provider**

```
Provider=IBMDA400;Data Source=MY_SYSTEM_NAME;
User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

*Where MY_SYSTEM_NAME is the name given to the system connection in OperationsNavigator*

**IBM Client Access OLE DB provider**

```
Provider=IBMDA400;Data Source=MY_SYSTEM_NAME;User Id=myUsername;
Password=myPassword;Default Collection=MY_LIBRARY;
```

*Where MY_SYSTEM_NAME is the name given to the System Connection, and MY_LIBRARY is the name given to the library in iSeries Navigator.*

Answer (score 1):

I just discovered you can create a file DSN using the ODCB Administration tool, for any type of ODBC driver.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [IBM documentation on ODBC connection string parameters](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=/rzaik/rzaikconnstrkeywordsservprop.htm).

Comment: +1 that reference actually  contains the i series odbc parameters

Answer (score 1):

Here's a great detailed description of what each keyword is and how you can configure them. The discusion is for DSN-less connections, in applications, but is useful if you want to customize your file DSN. I found it more useful than the IBM documentation.

http://www.sqlthing.com/HowardsODBCiSeriesFAQ.htm